# String.Format Method to align database output in a text file

Tags: c#, database, string, text-files, string.format

I know there a some other questions related to mine but still they do not help me very much. I tried to understand the concept of the String.Format Method but i failed over and over again and still have no clue how to use it in my case. I know it is asked very much but if someone has an idea how to get the alignment in place i would appreciate it a lot.

I'm saving the output of different database tables to different text files. I want to align the "name" of the column to its "value". This makes very much sense because in some tables there a lot of "null" values and that leads to a poorly formatted output. Because the "null" is not exported to that file and therefore the values are moved to the left.

[image: Database Table vs. Text File]

```
private void WriteSQLQueryOutputToTextFile(string DBUser, string DBUserPassword, string sqlQuery, string databaseName, string nameOfOutputFile)
{
    string pathOfOutputFile = dWTestResult + "\\DatabaseUpgradeCheck\\" + nameOfOutputFile;           

    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + 
    GetEnvironmentVariable.MachineName + "; Initial Catalog=" + databaseName + "; User ID=" + DBUser + "; Password=" + DBUserPassword + ";"))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, sqlCon);     
        try
        {
          sqlCon.Open();
          DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
          adapter.Fill(dataset, "nameOfDataset");
          string currentLine = "";
          foreach (var col in dataset.Tables[0].Columns)
          {
            currentLine += " " + col.ToString();
          }

         OutputHandler.AppendDataToFile(pathOfOutputFile, currentLine);

         foreach (DataRow row in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
         {
            currentLine = "";
            foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
            {
                currentLine += " " + item.ToString();
            }
            OutputHandler.AppendDataToFile(pathOfOutputFile, currentLine);
          }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        logger.Debug(ex, "Writing Database Output to the " + "\"" + nameOfOutputFile + "\"" + " file failed");
     }
     finally
     {
        sqlCon.Close();
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if the printed width of the data is greater than the printed width of the column name?

Comment: It should always aligned left to each other. Meaning, name of column and its data.

Comment: OK, please scroll down to see my answer which does what I think you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

string.Format is good when you know your required format in advance, less good if you have dynamic sources like the results of a query. Try something like this:

```
private void WriteSQLQueryOutputToTextFile(string DBUser, string DBUserPassword, string sqlQuery, string databaseName, string nameOfOutputFile)
{
    string pathOfOutputFile = dWTestResult + "\\DatabaseUpgradeCheck\\" + nameOfOutputFile;           

    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + 
    GetEnvironmentVariable.MachineName + "; Initial Catalog=" + databaseName + "; User ID=" + DBUser + "; Password=" + DBUserPassword + ";"))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, sqlCon);     
        try
        {
          sqlCon.Open();
          DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
          adapter.Fill(dataset, "nameOfDataset");
          string currentLine = "";
          var nameLengths = new int[dataset.Tables[0].Columns.Count];
          var i = 0;
          foreach (var col in dataset.Tables[0].Columns)
          {
            var colName = col.ToString();
            nameLengths[i] = colName.Length;
            currentLine += " " + colName;
            i++;
          }

         OutputHandler.AppendDataToFile(pathOfOutputFile, currentLine);

         foreach (DataRow row in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
         {
            currentLine = "";
            i = 0;
            foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
            {
                var field = item.ToString();
                currentLine += " " + field.PadRight(nameLengths[i], ' ');
                i++;
            }
            OutputHandler.AppendDataToFile(pathOfOutputFile, currentLine);
          }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        logger.Debug(ex, "Writing Database Output to the " + "\"" + nameOfOutputFile + "\"" + " file failed");
     }
     finally
     {
        sqlCon.Close();
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: This looks very good. Only issue is when the value is longer than the column name. Then the values are moved to the right. I made a screenshot. Any chance to avoid this in your example?https://s16.directupload.net/images/190412/2b34dcgi.jpg

Comment: You need to work out how wide each column COULD be, which requires you to calculate that instead of the width of the field name in the initial loop. You can work that out from the Column object in the header loop (what type is the field, how many characters can it hold (in the case of strings)). You should be able to work out the solution from that.

Comment: Well Steve, i'm hearing what you are saying. But i really don't have a clue how to do this. Maybe it is because c# and programming is very new to me. Sorry mate.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the length of the string representation of every column name and data value, you can work out the minimum width for each column and prepare a format string for that column which sets its minimum width.

Something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DataTable dt = SampleData();

            // Prepare the column formats
            int nCols = dt.Columns.Count;
            var dataWidths = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName.Length).ToList();

            foreach (DataRow d in dt.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < nCols; i++)
                {
                    dataWidths[i] = Math.Max(dataWidths[i], d.ItemArray[i].ToString().Length);
                }
            }

            var colFormats = dataWidths.Select(x => $"{{0,{-x}}}").ToList();

            //

            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            // Add the column names
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(" ", dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select((x, i) => string.Format(colFormats[i], x.ColumnName))));

            // Add in the data
            foreach (DataRow d in dt.Rows)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(string.Join(" ", d.ItemArray.Select((x, i) => string.Format(colFormats[i], x))));
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

            Console.ReadLine();


        }

        static DataTable SampleData()
        {

            DataTable sdt = new DataTable();
            string[] cn = "ARCHIVE DBDATETIME NEXTDOCID HIGHESTDISK SYSTEMTYPE FLAGS VERSION SINGLEUSER".Split(' ');

            foreach (string n in cn)
            {
                sdt.Columns.Add(n);
            }

            DataRow drn = sdt.NewRow();
            drn["ARCHIVE"] = "Hello";
            drn["DBDATETIME"] = 1316859;
            drn["NEXTDOCID"] = 1;
            drn["HIGHESTDISK"] = "Nothing";
            drn["SYSTEMTYPE"] = 1;
            drn["FLAGS"] = "ABC";
            drn["VERSION"] = "Hello";
            drn["SINGLEUSER"] = 256;
            sdt.Rows.Add(drn);

            drn = sdt.NewRow();
            drn["ARCHIVE"] = "Value longer than header";
            // No value for drn["DBDATETIME"] etc.
            drn["SINGLEUSER"] = 256;
            sdt.Rows.Add(drn);

            return sdt;
        }

    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
ARCHIVE                  DBDATETIME NEXTDOCID HIGHESTDISK SYSTEMTYPE FLAGS VERSION SINGLEUSER
Hello                    1316859    1         Nothing     1          ABC   Hello   256
Value longer than header                                                           256
```